# has anyone successfully configured FlashPAP app in 2004

Tags: 20.04, java, oracle

I am trying to install and configure FlashPAP which requires java.jar to execute. Have hit a wall (numerous times). Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED
It appears that my issue was NOT having required javafx files. Once I got to the bottom of that, my FlashPAP.jar file worked as designed.

OPs...you can delete/archive this question as you see fit. Thanks.
GordK

Comment: This answer might be useful for future visitors if you can describe these required javafx files and how you got them

Comment: accept the question when you can and the system will let it disappear from the frontpage. The answer might be obvious to some but will help someone new to this in the future. So no removing please :+

Answer (score 0):

Update to meet the requests of muru and Rinzwind...

I used the command 'sudo apt-get install openjfx' (without quotation marks)

That seemed to satisfy the error of 'JAVAFX files needed, not found'.
Apologies...I was messing with this java.jar business for so long that I don't have good breadcrumbs to give a clear description and history of my steps to eventual success. I did follow advice from many different forum entries on this forum and others to start this adventure. The command above is what finally brought it all together.
Thanks for the heads up in the follow up comments. That little tidbit may save someone else the headaches I experienced.
GordK